# how to parse laravel to json, and receive it from android

Tags: php, android, json, laravel

Hello I would like to know how to connect my Laravel base Web service to My Android Application? Currently im tried with both native and laravel code. and i manage to get the json from native php. but then when I Tried it in Laravel it returns the same json but unable to receive it in Android, the error says something about Doctype

For The Laravel in my Controller

```
    public function jsonview()
{
    $data2  =DB::table('item_list')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    $response = array();
    $response["status"] =1;
    $response["message"] = "getting data";
    $response["data"]=array();
    //$response["data"] = $data2;
    //or with
    foreach ($data2 as $data2) {
        $datas = array();
        //echo "lol";
        $datas["nama_item"] = $data2->nama_item;
        $datas["description"] = $data2->description;
        $datas["price"] = $data2->harga;
        $data = DB::table('users')->where("id","=",$data2->seller)->first();
        $datas["seller"] = $data->firstname;
        $datas["picture"] = $data2->pic_name;
        array_push($response["data"], $datas);
    }
    //dd(Request::json()->get('data'));

    return Response()->json(['data'=>$response["data"]]);
}
```

Returning Error in Android

it keeps Receiving

```
Value <!DOCTYPE
```

here are the full error code

```
04-21 21:38:06.541 14436-14514/skyvity.belisini E/JSON Parser: Error Parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

My Current Android Which works in native php but yet not receiving in Laravel

```
package skyvity.belisini.Controller;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import skyvity.belisini.Config.JSONParser;

/**
 * Created by Wilztan on 4/20/2016.
 */
public class ItemController {

//Listing Home
public  static JSONArray jsonArray= null;
public static ArrayList<String> Item = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> desc = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> seller = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> picture = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void list_item(){
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    JSONParser jsonParser= new JSONParser();
    JSONObject object jsonParser.request(JSONParser.base_url+"json",params);
    try {
        if(object.getJSONArray("data")==null){
            Log.v("not Failed in here","NULL JSON");
        }
        jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("data");
        Log.v("not Failed in here",jsonArray.toString());
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            Log.v("notFailed here","Lol");
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Item.add(jsonObject.getString("nama_item"));
            desc.add(jsonObject.getString("description"));
            price.add(jsonObject.getString("price"));
            seller.add(jsonObject.getString("seller"));
            picture.add(jsonObject.getString("picture"));
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("LOL" , e.toString());
    }
}}
```

:D

Comment: Test your route doing a request from your browser if it is GET or using POSTMAN to other type of request and see the data retrieved or the logs as @Dinar says.

Comment: @JoseRojas it returns as Json in Postman

Comment: But as we see, it returns something else in your android app.

Try to check if REST methods for routes are correct.

Try to set `any` for this route just for test.

Comment: It Works :D @Dinar , Thank You. The Problem is with that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens probably because your code shows error page. And it is HTML page and of course it contains DOCTYPE at the beginning.

Just check your logs for errors and fix them.

Comment: For Showing errors, Whihc one do you mean? In Browsers it returns the same view as the native one. probably i still mistaken which log did you mean?